# Preprocessing problem

Tags: c++, library, c, compile, c-preprocessor

I've a little problem, I'm trying to create a library with processor variables for tune it.

So in `.ino` I declared my preprocessor var, but preprocessor variables appear not defined in my library. (Notice that I've create a folder `test/test.h` in `libraries` directory of Arduino IDE)

Some code to reproduce the problem :

**test.ino** :

```
#define TEST

#include "test.h"

void setup() {}
void loop() {}
```

**test.h** (edited, reverse error message, this is solution)

```
#if defined(TEST)
  #error "DEFINED"
#else
  #error "NOT DEFINED"
#endif
```

If I compile it, I fall on `#error "NOT DEFINED"`.

Somebody with an idea ?

Have a good day

Comment: What you are doing should work IMO, have you tried `#define TEST (1)` ?

Comment: Note that using #defines in your sketch will have no effect at all on any usage of those defines in source code (.c and .cpp files), or the header file included in said source code files, in your library. It will only affect the single instance of the header file that is included in your sketch. Using #define in your sketch to configure a library is seldom does what you actually intend it to when you set out.

Comment: You should understand the concept of the [Translation Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) to get a better insight into why #define in the sketch won't affect your library's source code operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working properly. You have mixed up your error messages. The code should be:

```
#if defined(TEST)
  #error "DEFINED"
#else
  #error "NOT DEFINED"
#endif
```

UPDATE: The question was edited after the time of this answer to correct the mixed up error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Please, start by reading the [Writing a Library for Arduino Tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/LibraryTutorial). That will solve your question.